# Sort ranges in an array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a timesheet spreadsheet for our company and I need to sort the employees by each timesheet block (15 rows by 20 columns).  I have the following code which I had help with, but the array quits sorting once it comes to a block without an employee name (I would like these to be shuffled to the bottom).  Another complication I am having is there are numerous formulas in these cells and when I run it as is, it removes them.  I would like to keep these intact if at all possible.  Here's the code:

```
function sortSections() 
{
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //SETTINGS
  var sheetName = activeSheet.getSheetName(); //name of sheet to be sorted
  var headerRows = 53; //number of header rows
  var pageHeaderRows = 5; //page totals to top of next emp section
  var sortColumn = 11; //index of column to be sorted by; 1 = column A
  var pageSize = 65;
  var sectionSize = 15; //number of rows in each section

  var col = sortColumn-1;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = sheet.getRange(headerRows+1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows()-headerRows, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var data3d = [];
  var dataLength = data.length/sectionSize;
  for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
    data3d[i] = data.splice(0, sectionSize);
  }
  data3d.sort(function(a,b){return(((a[0][col]<b[0][col])&&a[0][col])?-1:((a[0][col]>b[0][col])?1:0))});
  var sortedData = [];
  for (var k in data3d) {
    for (var l in data3d[k]) {
      sortedData.push(data3d[k][l]);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(headerRows+1, 1, sortedData.length, sortedData[0].length).setValues(sortedData);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think to solve your problems is possible to use the [Range.sort](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#sort) function instead of the custom code. The sort function relocates also the formulas but in a tricky way - if a cell formula contains a cell reference, the sort function changes the row index in relocated cell to have the new cell row index, for instance, initially the cell `C1` contains the `=A1*B1` formula, after the sort operation the row 1 relocated to the row 3 and the cell 'C3' will contain not `=A1*B1`, but `=A3*B3`.

With this modification your code should looks something like this

```
function sortSections() 
{
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //SETTINGS
  var sheetName = activeSheet.getSheetName(); //name of sheet to be sorted
  var headerRows = 53; //number of header rows
  var pageHeaderRows = 5; //page totals to top of next emp section
  var sortColumn = 11; //index of column to be sorted by; 1 = column A
  var pageSize = 65;
  var sectionSize = 15; //number of rows in each section

  var col = sortColumn-1;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var range = sheet.getRange(headerRows+1, 1, sheet.getMaxRows()-headerRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  range.sort({column: sortColumn, ascending: true});
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at this.  Unfortunately, this only sorts consecutive rows.  I need sections of 15 rows each sorted; on row 54 I have an employee name in column 11 with 14 rows below belonging to that employee, then the next section starts on line 69 and so forth.  I need the 14 lines below to follow the top line of each section and  send any blank sections (w/o an employee name) to the end.  To add a wrinkle, after every 4 sections, there is a break of 5 lines (still waiting for Google spreadsheets to incorporate page breaks) that I would like to keep intact.

Comment: @user1637113, it is possible to iterate every section, get every section as a range and sort it. I gave only an example and not a complete solution.

Comment: I'm quite new at this, so bear with me; would I create a var for each section, then sort the variables by a cell reference in each? Or do I create range in the sheet itself and sort those?